# Continious stream of data via socket gets progressively more delayed

Tags: sockets

I am working on an application which, through a Java program, links two different robot simulation environments. One simulation environment (let's call it A) sends the current state of the robot to the Java application, which does some calculations and then sends data about this current state, as well as some other information, on to the other simulation environment (let's call it B). Simulation B then updates the state of the robot to match Simulation A's version.

The problem is that as the program continues to run, simulation B begins to lag behind what simulation A is doing. This lag increases continuously, so that after a minute or so simulation B is several seconds behind.

I am using TCP sockets to send data between these environments and the Java program. From background reading on socket programming, I found out it is bad practice to continuously open and close sockets rapidly, so what I am doing currently is just keeping both sockets open. I have a loop running which grabs data from Sim A, does some calculations, and then sends the position data to Sim B and then I have the thread wait for 100ms and then the loop repeats. To be clear, the position data sent to B is unaltered from what is received from A.

Upon researching the lag issue, someone suggested to me that for streams of data it is actually a good idea to open and close sockets, because if you keep the socket open, if one simulation takes a longer time to process things than the other, you end up with the position data stacking up in the buffer and being read sequentially, instead of reading the most recent data. Is this true? Would rewriting my code to open and close sockets every 100ms potentially get rid of the delay? Or is this not how sockets actually work?

Edit for clarification: It is more critical that the simulations stay in sync than that all position data is sent, in other words it is acceptable to not pass along all data points for the sake of staying in sync.

Besides keeping the socket open causing problems, does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing the lag issue?

Thanks in advance for any insight/suggestions/hints!

Comment: Most important piece of information that would be helpful: are you using TCP or UDP?

Comment: Oops, should have mentioned that! I'm using TCP sockets. I edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about using a single connection. Data can indeed back up, but using multiple connections doesn't change that.

The basic question here is whether the Java program can calculate as fast as the robot can send data. If it can't, it will get behind. You can do various things to the networking to speed it up but if the computations can't keep up they are futile. So you need to investigate your timings.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why using multiple connections wouldn't potentially fix a problem with data backing up. If I start closing connections, wouldn't all the data which is stacked get thrown out and then when the socket is opened again an up to date position would be sent? There might still be some lag in transmitting the data along due to time it takes to calculate things in the java portion, but the lag should no longer accumulate and grow worse over time. I'm not an expert in sockets by any means, so I might be missing something.

Comment: @JavaRobots Certainly the data gets thrown out, but you didn't say that was an acceptable outcome. Is it? You also need to consider that connecting takes time of its own.

Comment: It's more important that the two simulations are in sync than that every position gets passed along, so losing data points for the sake of staying in sync is acceptable. I should have definitely been more specific in my question when it comes to that.